# Convergence of $(1+1/n^{2})^{2n^2}$ using properties of subsequences

Tags: real-analysis

Establish the convergence and find the limit of the following sequence
$(1+1/n^{2})^{2n^2}$. I tried reindex using $m = n^2$, in which case $(x_m)$ converges to $e^2$. However, $(x_m)$ is a subsequence and I don't think I can use the convergence of a subsequence to establish convergence of the sequence. I have a theorem saying that if a sequence converges, its subsequence will converge to the same. Is there a way I can establish convergence of the original sequence?

Comment: A monotone sequence with a convergent subsequence is convergent.

Comment: You're not using "the convergence of a subsequence to establish the convergence of this sequence." You are using the convergence of a sequence to establish the convergence of a subsequence.

Comment: @BobKrueger I need to establish convergence of $(x_n)$, but I only know that the subsequence $(x_m)$ converges. I do want to show the sequence $(x_n)$ converges but am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with the sequence $x_m = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{m} \right)^{2m}$ which converges to $e^2$ and then pass to the subsequence $(x_{n^2})_{n=1}^{\infty}$. By the theorem you quote, any subsequence of $(x_m)_{m=1}^{\infty}$ must converge to the same limit and so

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^{2n^2} = e^2. $$